# Wp sheet editor plugin export issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, attributes, product-variations

I am using Wp sheet editor pro plugin to edit the variations and attributes which i have 700+ products on my website.

I have imported the content from my shopify store to WooCommerce store.

By default shopify's product attributes didn't match WooCommerce so they are create as custom attributes.

But in WooCommerce we want to use inbuilt attributes instead of custom ones.
so to edit this I am using wp sheet editor to it in bulk.

When I export the file which has WooCommerce built in attribute assigned it works fine, but when I export the file which has custom attributes the exported file shows the Numbers in rows and columns.
[image]

kindly suggest the solution to get the data and add the variations from excel

Comment: thats what i want to do it via excel, and importing those but they are showing coloumns are number 1,2,3